# how to make PDFTextStripper V2.0.* backward compatible to V1.8.*

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I upgraded pdfbox from 1.8 to 2.0, however we found the extracted text from same paf file has some diffrences, however we heavliy depends on the extracted formatted text by version 1.8, may I know how to make PDFTextStripper V2.0 compatible with PDFTextStripper V1.8?

Text extracted in V1.8

```
(Internal List)
Europe GmbH
Shipment Number: 6000047226        6000047226
Carrier: 7000001095                Loading start date: 24.07.2017  00:00:00
```

Text extracted in V2.0

```
(Internal List) Europe GmbH
Shipment Number: 6000047226        6000047226Carrier: 7000001095               Loading start date: 24.07.2017  00:00:00
```

Comment: There isn't. If you share the PDF one could investigate what's going on, or set parameters to influence line separation. The differences are probably because the many problems with fonts in 1.8 that were solved in 2.0.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4047 for an example. (`setIndentThreshold()` and `setDropThreshold()`)

Comment: *"how to make PDFTextStripper V2.0 compatible with PDFTextStripper V1.8?"* - A change in the major version usually implies some incompatible changes. So when you decided to update from 1.8 to 2.0, you surely planned to update code that depends on the API or on quirks of that 1.8 version, didn't you? That being said your exact issue might be an regression. In that case sharing your pivotal code and example PDFs would allow us to analyse that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Timan Hausherr and mkl's answers.

I have changed my code based on the new formatted content extracted by PdfBox V2.0.